# sqflite with flutter create table problem

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

I have a problem with my code, I wrote simple flutter app which is create account for persons  and save person information in sqlite database, but when I create tables it gave me errors this is my code and error:
my code:

```
Future<Database> openDb() async {
   
    if (db == null) {
      // get path of database
      final pathdb = await getDatabasesPath();
     
      final path = join(pathdb, 'roznamcha.db');
     
      db = await openDatabase(path,
          // create tables
          onCreate: (Database database, int version) async {
        await database.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE account (
      accountNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
      telphone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      address VARCHAR(100),
      issueDate DATETIME,
      balance INTEGER,
      image VARCHAR(255),
      type VARCHAR(64),
    )''');
        // transaction table
        await database.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE transaction (
      transactionNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      description TEXT NOT NULL,
      issueDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
      credit INTEGER,
      debit INTEGER,
      accountNum INTEGER,
      record BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
      rate INTEGER NOT NULL
    )''');
      }, version: 1);
    }
    return db;
  }
```

error :

> Exception has occurred. SqfliteDatabaseException
> (DatabaseException(near ")": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): ,
> while compiling: CREATE TABLE account (
> accountNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
> name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
> telphone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
> address VARCHAR(100),
> issueDate DATETIME,
> balance INTEGER,
> image VARCHAR(255),
> type VARCHAR(64),
> )) sql '    CREATE TABLE account (
> accountNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
> name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
> telphone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
> address VARCHAR(100),
> issueDate DATETIME,
> balance INTEGER,
> image VARCHAR(255),
> type VARCHAR(64),
> )' args []})

Comment: Remove the `,` from `type VARCHAR(64),`.

Comment: i romove, from my code but now it gave me this error:Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near "transaction": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE transaction ( @forpas

Comment: `transaction` is a reserved word in SQLite. Change it to something else.